# Getting error to unmarshalling object from xml using resttemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate of spring to invoke rest api getting error to unmarshall xml to object my code is:-

```
String  uri = "http://devd.webservice.com/devpl/api/1.0/credential?apiKey=" + apiKey + "&signature=" + signature + "&timeStamp=" + timeStamp;
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.set("accountName", accountName);
        requestHeaders.set("containerName", containerName);
        requestHeaders.set("folderPath", folderPath);
        requestHeaders.set("Content-Type","application/xml");
        requestHeaders.set("Accept","application/xml");
        RestTemplate template = getRestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        Credential result =(Credential)template.postForObject(uri,requestEntity,Credential.class);
```

Object classs bean on which i consume object:-

```
   package com.simplidrivechn.netmagicsolutions.bean;
    import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.*;

    @XStreamAlias("credential")
    public class Credential
    {
    private String DestinationUrl;
    private String AuthToken;
    private String StorageUrl;

        public String getAuthToken() {
            return AuthToken;
        }

        public void setAuthToken(String AuthToken) {
            this.AuthToken = AuthToken;
        }

        public String getDestinationUrl() {
            return DestinationUrl;
        }

        public void setDestinationUrl(String DestinationUrl) {
            this.DestinationUrl = DestinationUrl;
        }

        public String getStorageUrl() {
            return StorageUrl;
        }

        public void setStorageUrl(String StorageUrl) {
            this.StorageUrl = StorageUrl;
        }
      }
```

My spring configuration file:-

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
      <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
      </bean>
    </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

 <bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
  <property name="aliases">
    <props>
      <prop key="credential">com.simplidrivechn.netmagicsolutions.bean.Credential</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read [class com.simplidrivechn.netmagicsolutions.bean.Credential]; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: Credential : Credential
```

please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your exception, it looks like that `XStreamMarshaller's` aliases are not set correctly in your spring context. You must make sure that your keys are 'aliases', i.e. root element in your case. Is 'credential' the root element of the xml response you are trying to deserialize? Note that aliases are case sensitive. Following code works for me. Note `aliases.put("person", Person.class);`My xml response has root element 'person'. If I change this key to lets say 'Person' like `aliases.put("Person", Person.class);` I exactly get the exception like you.

```
XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<String, Class>();
aliases.put("person", Person.class);
marshaller.setAliases(aliases);
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(
                marshaller, marshaller);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
converters.add(converter);
template.setMessageConverters(converters);
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
ResponseEntity<Person> response = template.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.GET, request, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to define aliases is autoscan.

```
<bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <array>
            <value>com.simplidrivechn.netmagicsolutions.bean.Credential</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```